# Adding Where Clause Skews Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

This is the result set that I get returned using my query:

```
empname itemssold
JJ      14
```

But this is my desired result set:

```
empname itemssold
AA      0
BB      0
CC      0
DD      0
JJ      14
RR      0
```

It seems to pulls all employees until I add in the `where` clause to my query which makes me wonder if I am adding it in the wrong place, or am I setting up my query incorrectly?

Below is DDL & My query I use:

```
Create Table #ShowAll
(
  empname varchar(1000)
  ,empid varchar(100)
)

Create Table #Data
(
  empid varchar(100)
  ,itemssold int
  ,beenverified varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #ShowAll Values
('JJ', 'J1'), 
('AA', 'A1'), 
('BB', 'B1'), 
('CC', 'C1'),
('DD', 'D1'), 
('RR', 'R1')

Insert Into #Data Values
('J1','14', 'Yes'), 
('A1', '12','No'), 
('B1', '13', 'No')

Select sa.empname
    , Da.itemssold
FROM #ShowAll sa
LEFT JOIN #Data da
    ON sa.empid = da.empid
WHERE da.beenverified = 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must move the test on `beenverified`  from the `WHERE` clause to `LEFT ... ON ...`:

```
SELECT sa.empname
    , coalesce(Da.itemssold, 0)
FROM #ShowAll sa
LEFT JOIN #Data da
    ON sa.empid = da.empid 
    AND da.beenverified = 'Yes';
```

With a `LEFT JOIN`, when there is no match on `empid` between the two tables, this query (minus the `WHERE` clause) returns `NULL` for `beenverified` (and other columns from #Data):

```
empname itemssold   beenverified
JJ      14          Yes
AA      12          No
BB      13          No
CC      NULL        NULL
DD      NULL        NULL
RR      NULL        NULL
```

If `beenverified` is tested in the `WHERE` clause, it does not return rows where the condition is not met:

- `beenverified IS NULL`
- `beenverified <> 'Yes'` (i.e. `= 'No'`)

Only row `JJ` is then valid. With the test in the `WHERE` clause, this query behaves like an `INNER JOIN ...`.

`Coalesce` is then added in order to replace `NULL` by `0`.